# Derivation of stock price formula John C. Hull 9th Ed p309

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, itos-lemma

It says assuming a no-uncertainty Weiner process that models stock price:
$$
\Delta S = \mu S\Delta t
$$
Can be rearranged to (after taking the limit of $\Delta t \to 0$... 
$$
\frac{dS}{S}=\mu dt
$$
Then integrating between time 0 and T to get:
$$
S_T=S_0 e^{\mu T}
$$

I don't understand the last step. Are they integrating with respect to t? How does the exponential come about when there was no exponential in the prior equation?  Is this step a condensation of a complex calculation that they didn't show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simpler than you think. Hull is just solving an ODE.

You can naively put integral signs on both sides of the equation:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}S_t}{S_t} &=\mu \mathrm{d}t \\
\implies \int_0^T\frac{\mathrm{d}S_t}{S_t} &=\int_0^T\mu \mathrm{d}t\\
\implies \ln(S_T)-\ln(S_0) &=\mu T \\
\implies S_T&=S_0e^{\mu T}.
\end{align*}

Perhaps this makes it easier: Since $S_t$ is deterministic, it is a ``normal'' function. Thus, you may want to write $y(x)=S_t$. The above equation then turns into $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y} =\mu \mathrm{d}x\Leftrightarrow y'=\mu y$. So, it's simply about solving a first-order ODE.

Also note that $\frac{\mathrm{d}S_t}{S_t}=\mathrm{d}\ln(S_t)$, i.e. percentage returns correspond to log-returns if time is infinitesimal. So, you shouldn't be surprised to find an exponential here.

Comment: Ohhhh totally didn't see it as an ODE. Thanks. (wish they had that in the wording...)